# form contents not clearing submit button

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the form to clear once submitted content. but the page doesn't clear once submitted. how can I fix this issue

I have this code in the main.js file

```
// Clear form
document.getElementById('Forms').reset();
```

this form still won't reset

Au

```
            <div class="alert">Your message has been sent</div>
            <form id="contact">
                <br>
                <p>
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Subject</label>
                    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject">
                </p>
                <p class="full">
                    <label>Message</label>
                    <textarea name="message" rows="5" id="message"></textarea>
                </p>
                <p class="full">
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions. **Do not post pictures when you can post the actual text/code**.

Answer (score 0):

If you read carefully: `document.getElementById('Forms')...` Forms... Forms... sounds familiar? No?  Exactly! Use `'contact'` 'cause

```
<form id="contact">
```

and here's a quicky

```js
const contactForm = document.getElementById("contact");

contactForm.addEventListener("submit", function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  this.reset();
})
```

```css
#contact label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form id="contact">

  <label>
  Name
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
  </label>

  <label>
  Email Address
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
  </label>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: hi i did what you said , the problem now is when i click submit a spin loader shows up and freezes the page.

Comment: @BuildaholiczakZak hit F12 and read the errors in console. Given the provided HTML I cannot guess what's going on with your exact specific case. As you can see the above demo *works*... Any thoughts?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtoXz.png i added the information from the test. wasnt enough room to post so i uploaded image of the information. the page still wont clear

Answer (score -1):

You got wrong id in the js file
try

use this instead
 `document.getElementById('contact').reset();`